# Merging rasters identified by clipped raster index

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-modeler, indexing

I have a very large set of data heavy ECW aerial photos. There is a polygon vector index of the rasters which identifies the name and other attributes of each raster.  My end goal is to be able to merge the aerials in a given smaller area of interest defined by a polygon vector. If I try Clip Raster with Polygon from SAGA, I get an error (I will post this later as it takes a few hours for this error to generate) and my guess is that it becomes a memory issue at some point due to the large file sizes.

I can clip the aerial raster index to my area of interest but then I am left with a list of 20+ rasters that I will need to individually select when I go to merge or clip polygon with raster. And I will have to repeat this task many times over. I am wondering if there is a way to somehow merge and clip only the rasters within the AOI.

My guess is that the AOI would need to clip the index, the names from resulting clipped layer would then need to be extracted from the Attribute table and these would select the files from the Raster Directory to make the input into Merge or Clip Raster with Polygon. I have a model laid out in the Model Designer, but I'm missing the part that will filter the rasters based on the name from the clipped Index as input into the Merge algorithm. Does anyone have any ideas on how to best accomplish this or know of something that already accomplishes this task?

[image]

UPDATE: I found that SAGA Clip Raster with Polygon does not support ecw format hence the error. I was getting. Still, the process takes over an hour with all the rasters in the directory. I would like to think that the process outlined here would be much quicker if it can be made to work.

Comment: Try virtual raster instead of merging rasters.

Comment: Thank for this idea. It does "work". However, I noticed that the colors on the rasters taken from the virtual raster are a bit faded.  Checking the histogram returns the majority of values on less than 1 or just under 255 (ie blank areas outside of the limits of the aerials, while for the rasters which were created form manually selecting the rasters within the AOI does produce a more balanced histogram since the outliers are removed. Additionally, the virtual raster seems to lag the system quite a bit. I would still like to be able to select only the rasters within the AOI for this process.